# Lotus Notes Formula - Duplicate a document and carry over specific fields

Tags: lotus-notes

These are the steps I am taking -

1. Create a new document and fill in a few fields
2. Save the document
3. Click the copy button which I inserted as action bar (asks how many
   copies to make)
4. The document is then duplicated X amount of times

I am trying to carry over certain fields from the original document that I copied to minimize data entry. I am new to Lotus Notes Formula also.

The code I have so far for the copy action bar button:

```
num := @Prompt([OkCancelList]; "Choose amount"; "How many copies?"; "3"; "1":"2":"3":"4");

@For(n := 1; n <= @TextToNumber(num); n := n + 1; @PostedCommand([Compose]; ""; "Form1");  @PostedCommand([FileSave]))
```

The document copies itself with no problem but the fields remain empty. I have tried using @SetField but I think something is wrong while in the loop?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: This IS possible, but with formula language it will be very awkward.

You need to collect the information from your current context first:

```
_tempSubject := Subject;
_num := @Prompt([OkCancelList]; "Choose amount"; "How many copies?"; "3"; "1":"2":"3":"4");
@For(n := 1; n <= @TextToNumber(_num); n := n + 1; 
  @Command([Compose]; ""; "Form1");  
  @UpdateFormulaContext;
  FIELD Subject := _tempSubject;
  @PostedCommand([FileSave]))
```

You could also write `@SetField( "Subject"; _tempSubject )` if you like that more than the FIELD- statement, it does exactly the same (unless you use Notes 5 or older where it made a difference, 15 years ago)

This really is a task for using LotusScript, that is much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you please explain what _anotherValue is for and the FIELD statements? The fields I want to copy are named: 'Subject' for example and both documents contain the same field name.

Comment: _anotherValue is a variable name ( I always use underscore to identify them as variables, to distinguish them from fields). And FIELD is another annotation of @SetField... I changed the example accordingly...

Comment: Thanks for the help! The code looks great, and I understand each line. I tried running this formula but it's not copying over the data from Subject field to the newly created document. It creates as many duplicates as I specify, but keeping the fields empty. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, I did not take care... Replace `@PostedCommand([Compose]; ""; "Form1");`  with `@Command([Compose]; ""; "Form1");` as @PostedCommand only comes AFTER all other code is done...

Comment: That works much better! Thanks. Now the only thing is when I make 3 copies from a saved document, it creates 3 copies and only saving the last document while the first 2 stay in edit mode. can this be fixed as well.